# Create a .msi from a vm

Tags: vmware, windows-installer

A few years ago I worked a temp job where they created. msi files using an application that scanned a VMware virtual machine once, you then booted it up installed the thing you wanted and shut it down. The app would then re-scan and create a msi from the changes it found.

I can't remember the name and would really like to use it in my current job. Has anyone encountered this before and can you tell me what the application was?

Comment: Please [edit] and use punctuation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general concept you're talking about is called application virtualisation - and there's several solutions that revolve around it. From the reference to vmware, chances are you're talking about [vmware thinapp](http://www.vmware.com/products/thinapp/overview.html).  - there's other options such as [app-v](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_App-V) from microsoft as well

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that sounds a little more complicated than I was planning, I mainly wanted to create msi's for deployment via GPO using a simple technique.  VMware thinapp appears to go way beyond this virtualising the deployed application on the end users machine.

Comment: thinapp will let you create installable MSIs as well, and it does work exactly as you've described it.